# Configuring input shape to Masking + Dense Keras layers

Tags: python, keras

Here is the model:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Masking(mask_value=-1, input_shape=(x_t.shape[0], x_t.shape[1])))

model.add(Dense(60, kernel_initializer='random_uniform', activation=DENSE_ACTIVATION,
                    input_shape=(x_t.shape[1],)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(120, activation=DENSE_ACTIVATION, input_shape=(60,)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(1, activation=DENSE_ACTIVATION, input_shape=(120,)))
```

I can't seem to feed the model a valid `x_t`. I've tried various shapes and get various errors in response.

If I try a (n_samples, n_features) 2d matrix, I get an error:

> Error when checking input: expected masking_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (n_samples, n_features)

If I try a (n_samples, 1, n_features) 3d matrix, I get an error

> Error when checking input: expected masking_1_input to have shape (n_samples, 1) but got array with shape (1, n_features)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have non time-series data which has two dimensions `(sample dimension, feature dimension)`. When you define the `input_shape` you **do not** include the `sample_dimension` as that is added by Keras automatically. Therefore, try this.

`model.add(Masking(mask_value=-1, input_shape=(x_t.shape[1],)))`